# i could not solve this [Error] 'rand' was not declared in this scope in dev c++

Tags: c++, c, random

```
void Setup() {
    gameover = false;
    dir = STOP;

    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;

    fruitX = rand() % width; //display fruit in a random place
    fruitY = rand() % height; score = 0;
}
```

Comment: can anyone plzz help me

Comment: Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: There are many names that are not defined in that code snippet. Post the smallest code you can come up with that shows the problem.

Comment: [Warning] #pragma system_header ignored outside include file this error is showing up

Comment: most of the lib files like graphics.h,bios.h are missing in my dev c++

Comment: Prefer `<random>` for random numbers in C++. And at least `<cstdlib>` over `<stdlib.h>` in C++.

Comment: can you say me a site to download libraries for c++ like graphics.h,bios.h

Comment: Downloading random files from random web sites is an excellent way to turn your computer into an unbootable brick.

Comment: it is showing that i dont have the cstdlib.h directory

Comment: but i dont have a perfect compiler,like graphics.h and bios.h atre missing

Comment: `<cstdlib.h>` doesn't exist, it's either `<cstdlib>` or `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: Please check the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know how to ask. You must give more details.

Now your IDE is DevC++ not the language

Comment: Hi @DeepanKumar, welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions, it's helpful to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to best assist with helping your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of c code.